# show friends in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to access only friends in `ManyToManyField`. BUT it is not working for me.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to show only list of friends in `ManyToManyField`.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile",blank=True)

class Video(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',null=True)
    add_users = models.ManyToManyField(Profile,related_name='taguser')
```

I want to access friends in Video model's `ManyToManyField`

**What have i tried**

- I also did `ManyToManyField('friends`)` but it didn't worked for me.

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be Appreiated.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you define related_name in your `Profile` model `OneToOneField` `User`, Django will use lowercased model name to access related object. So, `user.profile`.

Or also you can get the related `friends` objects to `Video.user` with [**`_set`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference):

```
video = Video.objects.get(pk=pk)
video.user.profile.friends
# or 
video.user.profile_set
```

Note, you can remove [**`unique`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique)) option from `OneToOneField`:

> This option is valid on all field types except **ManyToManyField** and
> **OneToOneField**.

---

And to add friends to add_users:

```
video.add_users.add(*video.user.profile.friends)
```

> Note that `add()`, `create()`, `remove()`, `clear()`, and `set()` all
> apply database changes immediately for all types of related fields. In
> other words, there is no need to call save() on either end of the
> relationship.

Comment: But how can i insert it in `model field` (ManyToManyField) (add_users)?

Comment: I am trying to access user friends in `add_users`'s **ManyToManyField** NOT in `friends`

Comment: Do you want to add `friends` into `add_users`?

Comment: Yes Sir. I want to access `user friends` in **add_users**

Comment: @Smith, like this: `video.add_users.add(*video.user.profile.friends)`

Comment: You mean i should put it like `ManyToManyField(video.add_users.add(*video.user.profile.friends) ?`

Comment: No, `video = Video.objects.get(pk=pk)` then `video.add_users.add(*video.user.profile.friends)`

Comment: BUT i want to show full `ManyToManyField` in template

Comment: Yeah, then in template `{% for profile in video.add_users.all %}{{ profile.full_name}}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Will i will be able to select users in template ?

Comment: You can access all related objects in template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230095/discussion-between-nksm-and-smith).